# how to use font-faces in css file within spring 3

Tags: css, spring-mvc, font-face

I'm trying to use font-faces inside a style.css file. I have put my style font .ttf file into resources with Spring 3. When use font-faces i need to put the path to the .ttf file like this:

```css
@font-face{
       font-family: NosiferCaps-Regular;
       src: url('../fonts/1942/1942.ttf');
}

.myClass{
     font:39px/1.2 NosiferCaps-Regular, verdana ;
     text-shadow:2px 2px 9px gray;
}
```

So, how do I refer to "src: url('../fonts/1942/1942.ttf')" inside a style.css file with Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have mapped the resources folder, in the servlet-context.xml file as follows:

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Depending upon your resources mapping path, you can reference the font as follows:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: NosiferCaps-Regular;
    src: url('http://localhost:8080/{app_name}/resources/fonts/1942/1942.ttf');
}
```

Please substitute the {app_name} according to your application. I am using an otf font and it works.